# Is there any way to extract charts from excel and convert them to image format using java?

Tags: java, excel, formatting, apache-poi, xdoc

I am working on an application that generates a xdoc output with a series of charts and tables, whose data comes from a given excel file. Currently I have been able to generate the necessary charts and tables managing the data with Apache Poi and generating the actual charts in a separate excel file using GCExcel, nevertheless, Apache does not include support to turn XSSFChart objecs into images in order to insert them into the document, and GCexcel's unlicensed version doesn't allow me to exoprt charts to images either. Anybody knows a way in which I can work around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Check out Spire.XLS library.

[Download the free version here](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Download/xls-for-java-free.html)

[Read what you can do using the library (features)](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/free-xls-for-java/Features.html#.X6M5lmgzZEY)

[Official tutorial](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Java/Spire.XLS-for-Java/Program-Guide/Spire.XLS-Program-Guide-Content-for-Java.html)

[Convert the excel file to image](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Java/Spire.XLS-for-Java/Program-Guide/Conversion/Convert-Excel-to-Image-in-Java.html)

I am not sure if this will actually work because I did not implement something like this before.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried it but the free libraries of Spire only include Spire.pdf.

Comment: UPDATE: I tried using Spire, but the excel libraries were very expensive for me, although they provide very good solutions. I think the only possible way to achieve this using Apache is by copy-pasting manually the charts to the document.